# Generate dummy data with 60% 0's and 40% 1's

Tags: python, pandas

I want to generate a new column in my dataframe `df` which can take only two values i.e. 0 or 1. My dataframe currently has 1000 rows with other columns as well. I want to generate 0 and 1 in such a way that 60% of the values in the column are 0 and rest 40% 1.

I did the following :

```
generated_data = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():

      if index <= len(df) * 0.6 :
        generated_data.append(0)


      else : 
        generated_data.append(1)
```

The question is : How can this be achieved randomly. in my code top 60% of the rows are 0 and rest 1. I want to achieve the randomness in the creation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with `p` parameter if need each value has 60% chance to be `0` and 40% chance to be `1`.

For 60% 0's and 40% 1's use [`numpy.random.shuffle.`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) with all possible values generated before:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(1000)})
#print (df)

arr = np.ones(len(df))
arr[:int(len(df) * 0.6)] = 0
np.random.shuffle(arr)

df['new1'] = arr
df['new2'] = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=len(df), p=(0.6, 0.4))

print (df['new1'].value_counts())
0.0    600
1.0    400
Name: new1, dtype: int64

print (df['new2'].value_counts())
0    601
1    399
Name: new2, dtype: int64
```

Comment: If he wants it to a column, may be he can assign directly to the column. Then no need to do `.tolist()`. correct? .Something like `df['generated_data'] = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=len(df), p=(0.6, 0.4))`

Comment: This answer generated a column with each value has 60% chance to be 0 and 40% chance to be 1. It's different than 60% 0's and 40% 1's. Because the result (number of 0's) will be a binomial distribution rather than a fixed number.

Comment: @Hongpei - You are right, thank you, so added new solution.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want precisely 60% of 0 and 40% of 1, you could first create the column with `np.ones`and `np.zeros`, and then `shuffle` it :

```
import numpy as np

generated_data = np.concatenate([np.zeros(600), np.ones(400)])
np.random.shuffle(generated_data)
print(generated_data)
```